# Как найти ссылки в тексте? И их положение

Tags: java, android, строки

Здравствуйте. Есть текст моя программа делит его на предложения.
Но из-за возможных ссылок она будет делить текст на предложения не правильно.
Я нахожу точки по средству цикла и `charAt` также поступаю и с !!! ... И прочим.

Насколько я понял мне нужно найти возможные www. http https .ru ....
Как мне найти все ссылки в строке и узнать их местоположение что бы когда я искал точки и другие знаки не попал на эту ссылку?

Comment: Мне кажется должно работать, если установить проверку на пробел после точки. А ссылки бывают всякие `wap.click`, например.

Comment: Ссылки в субтитрах)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ссылки, на сколько мне известно, не содержат пробелов. Можно воспользоваться этим свойством и найти все точки, которые рядом с ними. Это будут заведомо точки не входящие в url.
Данный способ, не может обеспечить точное разделение на предложения, но по крайней мере, исключит ложные срабатывания на ссылках.

```
String text = "Насколько я понял мне нужно найти возможные" +
            " www. http https .ru .... Как мне найти все ссылки в " +
            "строке и узнать их местоположение что бы" +
            " http://www.yandex.ru/" +
            " когда я искал точки и другие знаки не попал на эту ссылку?";

for (String str : text.split("([\\s][.])|([.][\\s])"))
    System.out.println(str);
```

Вывод будет таковым:

> Насколько я понял мне нужно найти возможные www
>   http https
>   ru
>   ..
>   Как мне найти все ссылки в строке и узнать их местоположение что бы http://www.yandex.ru/ когда я искал точки и другие знаки не попал на эту ссылку?

Comment: Хорошая идея, просто надо ещё ж на всякие ! ? ; ... ??? !!! Проверять ...эм...

Comment: Узнать бы просто местоположение я б засунул бы её координаты в массивы и когда цикл крутился б я забраковал бы не нужные промежутки.

Comment: У меня в главе просто пока крутиться что то с циклом и много

Comment: @ДмитрийБережной можно ж дополнить регулярку для нужных символов

Comment: Я просто с регулярной не знаком)))) буду учить тогда)) а то у меня метод на 200 строчек может по проще получиться